# Regex lookahead for a colon but ignore substitutions

Tags: regex, makefile, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to detect wether a line in a Makefile is the start of a "rule". Rules have the syntax `<rule-name> : <rule-prerequisities>`. So, easy right? I'll just look ahead for a colon:

```
(?=[^:]+:(?!=))
```

The negative lookahead is there to distinguish between variable assignments. They can have the form `FOO := foo`.

However, now I also have things like this:

```
$(FOO:.c=.o) : baz
```

Here the variable `FOO` is evaluated, but every `.c` occurrence is replaced with `.o`. Now it'll detect that this is a rule, but in the "wrong" way.

The problem is further compounded by this particular line:

```
ifneq ($(words $(subst :, ,$(CURDIR))), 1)
```

Here, the lookahead matches, because it finds a colon not followed by an equals sign.

Basically, what I need to do is I need to lookahead for a colon, but ignore anything inside variable substitutions.

TL;DR: How can I lookahead for a colon but ignore variable substitutions?

[regex101 link here](https://regex101.com/r/9FmdB5/1), I want to match everything except the last three lines.

Comment: A very simple solution could be some version of this: `:(?!=)(?!.*?\))`. Check it out [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZZRfbm/1). It simply checks for a colon, not followed by an equal sign, and not followed by a closing parentheses.

Comment: That doesn't work with a line like `$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)`

Comment: TL;DR: Use a proper parser instead of RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but I think it'll work.

```
^                              # Start of line
[^()\r\n]*                     # Any number of non parentheses characters
(?:\([^()\r\n]*(?:\([^()\r\n]*(?:\([^()\r\n]*(?:\([^()\r\n]*\))?[^()\r\n]*\))?[^()\r\n]*\))?[^()]*\))?
[^()\r\n]*                     # Any number of non parentheses characters
:(?!=)                         # Colon NOT followed by an equal-sign
[^()\r\n]*                     # Any number of non parentheses characters
(?:\([^()\r\n]*(?:\([^()\r\n]*(?:\([^()\r\n]*(?:\([^()\r\n]*\))?[^()\r\n]*\))?[^()\r\n]*\))?[^()]*\))?
[^()\r\n]*                     # Any number of non parentheses characters
$
```

The two uncommented lines eat up to four levels of nested parentheses. Could be be expanded to more levels if necessary.

It matches the beginning of the string up to a possible group of parentheses, "skipping" that, and then continues up to a colon **not** followed by an equal sign. Then it matches up to another possible group of parentheses (skips), and continues to the end of line.

Caveats: If there are more than one group of parentheses before **or** after the colon, it won't work. More groups could be added by duplicating the parentheses-eater though ;) But I don't think the aim was to see how complex we can make a regex ;)

[Update to your example at regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/9FmdB5/3).